# Export a list of methods & params in library to a text file

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a huge solution where I want to export a list of all methods in all classes to a text file, including their parameters.

For example:

```
public static class MyMath
{
    public static bool InRange(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, byte Range)
    {
        return (System.Math.Max(System.Math.Abs(x1 - x2), System.Math.Abs(y1 - y2)) <= Range);
    }
    public static int PointDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        return (int)System.Math.Sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    }
    public static int Generate(int Min, int Max)
    {
        return new Random().Next(Min, Max);
    }
}
```

I'd like to export that to a text file like this:

```
bool MyMath.InRange(x1, y1, x2, y2, Range)
```

or

```
bool MyMath.InRange(double, double, double, double, byte)
```

I just need a way to get the methods & params via Reflection to print it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var type = typeof (MyMath);
sb.AppendFormat("Class Name: {0}", type.Name);
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("Methods: ");
sb.AppendLine();
foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
{
     sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}.{2}( ", method.ReturnType.Name, type.Name, method.Name);
     foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
     {
         sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1},", param.GetType().Name, param.Name);
     }
     sb.Remove(sb.ToString().Length - 1, 1);
     sb.Append(")");
     sb.AppendLine();
}

 var content = sb.ToString();
 File.WriteAllText("deneme.txt",content);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks alot, I overcomplicated my attempts obviously..

Answer (score 1):

1. Getting the assemblies
2. Iterate throw types of each assemby using `assembly.GetTypes();`
3. Iterate threw methods of each type using `type.GetMethods();`
4. your can get your method name using : `methodInfo.Name`
5. You can get your method parameters using `methodInfo.GetParameters()`
6. You can get the method return type using : `methodInfo.ReturnType`

Exemple code :

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    var types = assembly.GetTypes();
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var methodes = type.GetMethods();
        foreach (var methodInfo in methodes)
        {
            var myMethodName = methodInfo.Name;
            var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            var returnType = methodInfo.ReturnType;

            // Write to your text file
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"E:\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll");
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    foreach (MethodInfo m in t.GetMethods())
        s.Append("\n" + m.ToString() + " ");
}
```

and then write `s` to your text file.